# API from Survey Monkey to Embarcadero (Database)

Tags: surveymonkey

How do I access Survey Monkey's API for non-app developers? I don't have an app, but just want the API to insert data from Survey Monkey into my database. Survey Monkey appears to only have an API authorization option for app developers.

Answer (score 1):

To insert it in the db you're going to have to have an app of some description to call the API and then convert the data into whatever your DB schema is.  You don't technically need a web app - you can generate an authorization token via the API console and then use that to make API calls.

Your other option is to use one of the export options through the site's Analyze tool and then use something to convert that into your DB.